# Flutter app not working in apk-release but works in debug mode (even after giving internet permissions)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

My app works fine in debug mode. I followed all the steps mentioned in flutter docs for making apk-release. I even mentioned the internet permissions for the apk-release in AndroidManifest file. My apk-release builds perfectly fine. But when i install it in my phone and try to use the app(Basically login using phone number cause the first page in my app is the login page), it doesnt respond. I figured there must be some problem with the internet permissions but I rechecked everything. It all works fine when i install the debug apk from Android Studio, but the release apk is somehow unable to communicate with the authentication servers. Please help me.

Btw, I updated all the dependencies in pubspec.yaml like cloudfirestore versions and stuff. Still no change. Also, I guess my SHA1 key is right in firestore. I also had to rename my package name from com.example.pareez to com.rishav.pareez but I am sure I made no mistake in that.
I ALSO USED THE SAME key.jks WHICH I USED TO MAKE AN APP YESTERDAY.

UPDATE - I uninstalled the previously installed apk from my phone and I used flutter install from my pc and then the app ran perfectly well. I guess installing manually is giving me problems. But i installed other apps manually too, and they worked fine.

Comment: try adding updated google json file in android folder with updated package name

Comment: Already did that bro. Didnt work.

Comment: try running in profile mode and see the exceptions

Comment: did you resolve it ? I have exactly same issue, I want to test app on real android device and internet doesnt work

Comment: No that issue was specific to only that app. Coudn't find a solution.

Comment: Now Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Build your aab bundle or apk using the below commands.**

1. For aab bundle:

   flutter build appbundle --no-shrink
2. For apk:

   flutter build apk --no-shrink

This solution worked for me. I hope, this will also help you. Thanks for asking this question.

Comment: what is the solution for archive file?